# filtering before joining django orm

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have three imaginary models:

```
 class Singer(BaseModel):
    singer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    album  = ForeignKey(album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                         related_name="singer_album")

 class Album(BaseModel):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True) 

 class Fan(BaseModel):
    fan_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True) 
    admired_singer = ForeignKey(Singer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                         related_name="fan_singer")
```

now lets say I want to query all singers + albums starting with 'g' that belong to the singer that the fan 'RSNboim' admired.

my intuition is to go like

```
queryset = Fan.objects.values('admired_singer','album_name').filter(fan_name = 'RSNboim', album_name__startswith='g')
```

**and now is my primary Question**

my real DB is running on about 6M records so I wish I could force Django to *filter* before it executes the *join* statement because it's consuming more effort first to join and only then filter by criteria.

will inserting the `filter()` before the `values()` actually execute filtering before joining?
or does Django/Postgres have their own way of prioritizing the operation's order?

Comment: Make a note that values() itself doesn't join anything, unless used with annotate, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call filter(), order_by(), etc. after the values() call, that means that these two calls are identical:

```py
Blog.objects.values().order_by('id')
Blog.objects.order_by('id').values()
```

This is stated in the official django doc.
Since this is a chrome link, I am unable to embed it.

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#:~:text=Finally%2C%20note%20that%20you,).values()
```

Open the link in chrome, to go to the highlighted section or you can search the text I posted in the django site.

Comment: thanks! so how can I 'force' Django to filter before joining?

Comment: @RSNboim Django automatically filters first before values, so you don't have any performance loss here.